# Cannot get added Method and link_to to work (Rail 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, path, routes, link-to

Seen some references, but its old Rails 2 solutions.  Having a hard enough time understanding some of the Rails 3 nomenclature.

I added a method 'dndl' in my controller.
I added a link_to in my index.
I TRIED and TRIED again to put routes in.

```
Controller:
def dnld
  blah blah
end
```

Index:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', stock %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_stock_path(stock) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Dnld', dnld, {:action => 'dnld'} %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', stock, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

Routes:

```
  resources :stocks do
    collection do
        put 'dnld'
    end
  end
```

I've tried:

```
    <td><%= link_to 'Dnld', stock, {:action => 'dnld'} %></td>
# End up on the stock show page with dnld not executed to my knowledge

    <td><%= link_to 'Dnld', , {:action => 'dnld'} %></td>
# Produces an error

    <td><%= link_to 'Dnld', dnld_stock_path(stock), {:action => 'dnld'} %></td>
# It doesn't know what dnld_stock_path is, yet I don't understand why it DOES know what edit_stock_path is and cannot find documentation to explain this.
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are giving collection in your routes.rb like:

```
  resources :stocks do
    collection do
        put 'dnld'
    end
  end
```

then the named path will be 'dnld_stocks_path'. And you don't need to specify the action.

```
<td><%= link_to 'Dnld', dnld_stocks_path %></td>
```

If you are giving member in your routes.rb like:

```
  resources :stocks do
    member do
        put 'dnld'
    end
  end
```

then the named path will be 'dnld_stock_path(stock)'.

```
<td><%= link_to 'Dnld', dnld_stock_path(stock) %></td>
```

For more info [visit](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)

Comment: I also needed the answer from kishi above.  I used the member call.  But I think the :as => dnld is necessary from kishi above.  And in the link_to, I used: <%= link_to 'Dnld', dnld_stock_path(stock) %>  That made the URL */stocks/2/dnld which is what I needed.  Changing from PUT to GET also cured me.  I don't totally understand why (noob) but I'm getting the result I wanted.  Don't forget tor "rake routes".

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 resources :stocks do
    collection do
        put :dnld, :as => dnld
    end
  end
```

then

`<%= link_to "Dnld", dnld_controllername_path %>`

Comment: Thanks Kishi.  Gave the dude below the credit to improve his score, but I couldn't have done it without your :as => dnld segment.